# Hay alguna forma de organizar todos los archivos de encabezado, separadamente de los .cpp?

Tags: c++, poo, git, vs2017

[image]

Anteriormente se mostraban los archivos de encabezado separados en subgrupos, pero luego de unos pulls del repositorio algo falló,

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.